# Different types of augmentations to be used for APR?

Tags: object-detection, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I am trying to do automatic number plate recognition but I have very few data. In order to increase the data, I tried translation, rotation and addition of noise. Can someone suggest me some other data augmentation techniques, which can be used in ANPR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use also :Rectification;Aspect-Ratio;Centring;Scaling;Mirroring;Cropping;Flipping H&V